# Shift + Romaji => Katakana, MacOS like behavior

Tags: japanese

To input Japanese scripts, I am using iBus and its romaji input.
To input Japanese katakana, I want to use shift key. For instance,

`a -> あ
shift a -> ア
ka -> か
shift ka -> カ`

I have heard similar things can be achieved on MacOS. Can I do this on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open MOZC Settings > Advanced Tab

[image: Mozc_settings window]

Click ✅`Apply`.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, do you know how to do a similar thing in かな input? This seems to only work with Romaji input mode.

Comment: `Mozc Settings` > `General` Top column Basic `Input Mode` set to `Kana`

Comment: After I did that, the shift katakana switch stopped working.

Comment: That's because Kana Input needs shift to type different Hiragana, e.g. ゃ ゅ ょ and so on. When you type a word to be Katakana, press F7 or Ctrl+K, it will do. Or you can buy a Japanese keyboard, there is a Katakana key, if you have a few extra keys unused, you can set them.